# Anchor и BottomSheet

Tags: android, android-layout, coordinator-layout

Хочу сделать, что бы когда `BottomSheet` появлялся на экране, что бы поднималась и `View` вместе с ним, для этого использую `CoordinatorLayout` и `Anchor`, проблема в том, что `BottomSheet` поднимается, а `View` остается внизу:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:emojicon="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/colorMain"
        android:titleTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        app:subtitleTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvChat"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rvWriteMessage"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <!-- include bottom sheet -->
    <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet" />

<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rvWriteMessage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/llBottomSheet"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rvIcons"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        <!--android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"-->

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/rvInside"
            android:background="@color/colorGreyTransparent" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rvInside"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            >


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgSticker"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_tag_faces_24dp" />

            <io.github.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText
                android:id="@+id/etMessage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgCamera"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_edit_text"
                android:hint="@string/conversation_activity_hint"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@color/colorMain"
                emojicon:emojiconSize="32sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgCamera"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSend"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnSend"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_rectangle"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_send" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Layout для `BottomSheet`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/llBottomSheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="200dp"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Bottom sheet content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Что сейчас получается при подъеме BottomSheet (rvWriteMessage остается внизу экрана):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end" Поиграйте с этим значением. Я когда прикреплял fab к bottomsheet с помощью анкора мне помогло app:layout_anchorGravity="right", а вот если б я использовал app:layout_anchorGravity="end", то тогда бы не так работало)

Comment: помогло или еще не получается?)

Comment: @iFr0z еще не получается

Comment: мб android:layout_above="@+id/rvIcons" сбивает?)

Comment: @iFr0z Та вроде бы нет